# jQuery-UI Resizable: scale all alsoResize elements in proportion with resizable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, math, jquery-ui-resizable

I have a resizable div which is positioned over a selection of elements which have been set to alsoResize.

Visually, the resizable element is a bounding box for the alsoResize elements.

I want to be able to resize the alsoResize elements in proportion of the resizable div. UI's default behaviour makes each element have a fixed left and top position when resizing:

http://jsfiddle.net/digitaloutback/SrPhA/2/

But I want to adjust the left and top of each AR element to scale with the bounding box as it's resized.

I first thought this wouldn't be too much hassle by altering the alsoResize plugin. This is  what I added to the resize: _alsoResize:

```
// Get the multipliers
var scaleX = self.size.width / os.width;
var scaleY = self.size.height / os.height;

newElW = ( parseInt(el.css('width')) * scaleX );
newElH = ( parseInt(el.css('height')) * scaleY );
newElL = ( parseInt(el.css('left')) * scaleX );
newElT = ( parseInt(el.css('top')) * scaleY );

el.css({ width: newElW, height: newElH, left: newElL, top: newElT });
```

As you'll see, the boxes lag somewhat:

http://jsfiddle.net/digitaloutback/SrPhA/4/

Something seems to be ballooning the figures and can't quite figure it out, any suggestions appreciated. Possibly discrepancy of decimal places between scripts & browser?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you need to rethink the structure..

You could insert the `.lyr` elements inside the `.resizer` element and position them inside it with percentage positions .. this way they will automatically resize while their container is changing size. (*the plugin does not have to handle them*)

**demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/SrPhA/65/

---

**Update after comment**

To de-couple the `resizer` from the *`alsoResize`* elements you will need to take a couple of things into consideration for the calculations.

- Firstly, you need to use the starting dimensions/positions and not the current of the elements, so use `start.width` `.height` etc..
- for the positioning you need to translate the element to the origin (*in regards to distance from the `resizer`*) scale the left/top and then re-translate back to where they were..

the final calculations become

```
newElW = start.width * scaleX;
newElH = start.height * scaleY;
newElL = ((start.left - op.left) * scaleX) + op.left;
newElT = ((start.top  - op.top ) * scaleY) + op.top ;
```

It needs some more tinkering to handle the case were you scale the elements by dragging the top or left side of the resizer..

**demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/SrPhA/171/

---

**Latest Update**

to handle scaling in all directions use these helpers..

```
utils: {
        west: function(start, op, scale, delta) {return ((start.left - op.left) * scale) + op.left + delta.left},
        east: function(start, op, scale, delta) {return ((start.left - op.left) * scale) + op.left;},
        south: function(start, op, scale, delta){return ((start.top  - op.top ) * scale) + op.top; },
        north: function(start, op, scale, delta){return ((start.top  - op.top ) * scale) + op.top + delta.top; }
    }
```

Working example with all updates at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/SrPhA/324/

Comment: I did consider this option and although still not out of the question, it would mean losing a lot of ground. In addition I'll be asking a lot more out of the script. The 'marquee' will need to wrap around any number of objects in realtime so that's a lot of wrapping and unwrapping which isn't currently there. Will test nonetheless so thanks for the input.

Comment: That is a big improvement Gaby. However the dimensions are still bloating somewhere - try dragging the marquee in and out a few times and the marquee starts pulling away from the inner elements. This may be a discrepancy when rounding the pixels, do you think?

Comment: In fact, the inaccuracy occurs whenever you release and re-click a handle.

Comment: @Will, a slight improvement might be to store and use the precise calculations after the first move, instead of re-starting from the integer values returned from the css/positioning.. so check http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/SrPhA/313/

Comment: I'm happy with the accuracy of this, I am now trying to make the inner elements resize when using the other handles. Here is what I have so far, starting with SW and W handles. I must be nearly there... http://jsfiddle.net/digitaloutback/SrPhA/322/

Comment: @will, here you go http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/SrPhA/324/ The only differene between east/west and north/south is the addition of the `delta.left` and `delta.top` respectively..

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to use `+` instead of `*`?

```
newElW = (parseInt(el.css('width')) + scaleX);
newElH = (parseInt(el.css('height')) + scaleY);
newElL = (parseInt(el.css('left')) + scaleX);
newElT = (parseInt(el.css('top')) + scaleY);
```

Comment: No - they are multipliers, effectively adding a percentage.

Answer (score 0):

I had a little luck by setting the margin-top and margin-left for positioning and leaving the 'top' and 'left' attributes at default for animation.

http://jsfiddle.net/SrPhA/97/

Comment: Not quite what I was after as the 'inner' elements are still fixed.